# Laravel Eloquen Model Join

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Good day everyone! I have a scenario here:

**Applications table**

```
-application_no
-record_id
```

**Requiremens table**

```
-req_id
-req_desc
```

**RequirementsChecklist table**

```
-req_id
-record_id
```

A single application has many requirements. Now I want to return the application together with its requirement_checklist and its requirement description(

> req_desc from Requirement table

)

The example output should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "application_no": "201911213",
        "record_id": '322',
        "requirements": [
            {
                "req_id": 1,
                "record_id": 322,
                "status": 1,
                "remarks": "",
                "requirementDefinition": "Some requirement description"
            },
            {
                "req_id": 2,
                "record_id": 322,
                "status": 1,
                "remarks": "",
                "requirementDefinition": "Some requirement description"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I was able to produce something like that, but I'm getting null on the `requirementDefinition key`

Here are my Model:

Application Model

```
 public function requirements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RequirementChecklist::class, 'record_id');
    }
```

RequirementChecklist Model

```
public function requirementDefinition()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Application::class, 'record_id');
    }
```

And my query:

```
$requirements = Application::where(['application.application_no' => $id])
                            ->with('requirements.requirementDefinition')

                            ->get();
```

Any idea on how I can join the Requirement table to get the req_desc? Thank you!

Comment: Im not sure but I think you mean to join requirements table (Requirement::class, 'req_id`) in the requirementsDefinition relationship..

Comment: The same result, requirementDefinition getting null value.

Comment: Finally got it to work!

Comment: @NetherMariano Please post your solution as an Answer to your own Question here, otherwise other people cannot learn from your question to solve their own problems.